# Delete an object from an array in Express Mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

```
{
  "_id": "608c3d353f94ae40aff1dec4",
  "userId": "608425c08a3f8db8845bee84",
  "experiences": [
    {
      "designation": "Manager",
      "_id": "609197056bd0ea09eee9429c"
    },
    {
      "designation": "Asst. Manager",
      "_id": "608c530de8ade5221b0e6d4e"
    },
    {
      "designation": "Sr. Manager",
      "_id": "608c534be8ade5221b0e6d4f"
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to delete object in array with id 608c530de8ade5221b0e6d4e, here is my code but that gives me error.

This is the controller:

```
const userId = req.userData.userId;
const id = req.params.id;
    
Experience.findOneAndUpdate({ userId: userId }, { $pull: { 'experiences': { '_id': id } }}, { multi:true }, function(err, obj) {
                  //   //do something here
});
```

This is model:

```
const newExpSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  designation: { type: String,  default: ""},
});

const experienceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  experiences: [newExpSchema],
});

export default model("experience", experienceSchema);
```

I am getting below error on { $pull: { 'experiences': { '_id': id } }}
Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3 .........
.......
The expected type comes from property '$pull' which is declared here on type 'UpdateQuery<Document<any, {}>>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
Folder.findOneAndUpdate({
  "_id": "608c3d353f94ae40aff1dec4"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "experiences": {
      "_id": "608c530de8ade5221b0e6d4e"
    }
  }
},
{
  "multi": false
})
```

Here is a working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YtNGBTr52U9

Comment: oh sorry, these numerics are just for example, actual strings are there.

Comment: Can you test it in working example? Does it work?

Comment: No overload matches this call. I am getting this same error after using your solution.

Comment: But it is working in the demo that I added to question, and I used the same data from your question. Can you copy your exact code to the question?

Comment: I have updated the question with real data and code. Please take a look

Comment: I updated my answer and added a new working example. Can you check it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231955/discussion-between-ds97-and-nenad-milosavljevic).

Comment: Can you check the chat channel?